# The trouble with multidimensional arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am struggling with multidimensional arrays in C. I'm trying to understand by example, to initialize and fill a 2 dimensional array, and to then be able to change the array values.
My first challenge is to try and print out the values of the array, but I am getting garbage back.

Please can anyone tell me how to get inside of a created array, to do things to it?

My code:

```
//checking out multidimensional arrays and stuff.

#include <stdio.h>

void multiarray(int a);

int main (void)
{
    printf("What size of square array? ");
    int size;
    scanf("%d", &size);
    multiarray(size);
    return 0;
}

void multiarray(int size)
{
    int array[size][size];
    int count[size * size], i = 0, k = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < size; ++row)
    {
        for(int column =0; column < size; ++column)
        {
            //initializing:
            array[row][column] = count[i++];
            //(*(array + row))[column] = count[i++];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
        {
            printf("val= %d, pos=array[%d][%d] \t", array[i][j], i, j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get:

```
./multiarray 
What size of square array? 4

val= -213241928, pos=array[0][0]    val= 32766, pos=array[0][1]     val= -109132576, pos=array[0][2]    val= 32577, pos=array[0][3]     
val= -213241920, pos=array[1][0]    val= 32766, pos=array[1][1]     val= -109143536, pos=array[1][2]    val= 32577, pos=array[1][3]     
val= 1, pos=array[2][0]     val= 0, pos=array[2][1]     val= 0, pos=array[2][2]     val= 0, pos=array[2][3]     
val= -213241880, pos=array[3][0]    val= 32766, pos=array[3][1]     val= -111404672, pos=array[3][2]    val= 32577, pos=array[3][3
```

Comment: you never iniitizalized your `count` array, so you're initializing `array` with whatever garbage is in `count`...

Comment: What values do you think are in your `count[size * size]` array that you assign to your 2-dimensional array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the values in `count` array, which itself is not initialized, and thus contains garbage values.

```
array[row][column] = count[i++];
```

---

Initialize the `count` array with values.

```
for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &count[i]);
}
```

Comment: Whoops. Sina strikes dumb once again.

Answer (score 3):

The only problem is that you do not initialize your count[] array.

If you write

```
int count[size * size] = {0};
```

It will initialize all the elements to zero.

Answer (score 2):

So your problem is with the count array... why is this an array? just make it an integer.

```
int array[size][size];
int count = 0, i = 0, k = 0;
for (int row = 0; row < size; ++row)
{
    for(int column =0; column < size; ++column)
    {
        array[row][column] = count++;
    }
}
```